# Measure height or g value using android phone

Tags: android

Is it possible to measure in which height phone is currently in- using android application ?

as like we calculate height from the g (gravity ) or any other possible ways like using Gyroscope/GPS position or anything integrated with phone?

If possible then how can i use it ?

Comment: Theoretically yes but the calibration and resolution of the gravity sensor can be problematic due to latitude and the amount of significant digits available.

Comment: do you realize the precision needed to obtain an usable altitude from the measure of gravity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the gps api provides a way:
the Location instance  has a getaltitude funktion

You can get the actual G  using the g sensor  (you have to make a vector addition )
But this cant be used unless the phone is standing still an I doubt that the sensors are precise enough .